# Serialize python parent class from inherited class to JSON - possible or stupid?

Tags: python, json, serialization

I know there are a lot of question on JSON serialization, but I'm still not grasping this it seems.

Given the following class:

```
import json

class BaseMongoObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def jsonify(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict)
```

And the following derived class:

```
from assetfacts import AssetFacts
from bmo import BaseMongoObject

class Asset(BaseMongoObject):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseMongoObject.__init__(self)
        self.facts = AssetFacts()
        self.serial = None
```

Trying to call `asset.jsonify()` by using the following piece of test code:

```
from asset import Asset

def test_me():
    a = Asset()
    a.serial = '123asdf'

    print a.jsonify()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_me()
```

Produces the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../bin/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    test_me()
  File "../bin/test.py", line 13, in test_me
    print a.jsonify()
  File "/Users/vlazarenko/MP/ac/lib/bmo.py", line 8, in jsonify
    return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/Users/vlazarenko/MP/ac/lib/bmo.py", line 8, in <lambda>
    return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict)
AttributeError: 'Asset' object has no attribute '_BaseMongoObject__dict'
```

Where am I going braindead about this? Ideally I wouldn't wanna be bothered with amount of levels of inheritance, just serialize all the way from the top.

Comment: Did you write the code in the first snippet? If so, did you actually mean `self.__dict` or did you mean `self.__dict__`?

Comment: My my my... Please shoot me. Thank you! :)

Comment: Add it as the answer and I'll accept it. :) Thanks again, I almost couldn't believe my eyes that this doesn't work and it was something I am overlooking for an hour already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to jsonify `self.__dict__` instead:

```
def jsonify(self):
    return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
```

Names that only *start* with a double underscore are [mangled to protect them from accidental overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162234/what-is-the-benefit-of-private-name-mangling-in-python) in a subclass, `.__dict` was rewritten to `._BaseMongoObject__dict`.

Comment: Yep, thanks. As pointed out in comments by @delnan it was indeed a classic typo I was overlooking stubbornly. (edit) 5 min to accept :)