# Instance attribute that has a name starting with two underscores is weirdly renamed

Tags: python, private, name-mangling, double-underscore

With the current implementation of my class when I try to get the value of a private attribute using class method I get `None` as the output. Any Ideas on where I'm going wrong?

**Code**

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Search(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def search_products_by_name(self, name):
        print('found', name)


class Catalog(Search):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__product_names = {}
    
    def search_products_by_name(self, name):
        super().search_products_by_name(name)
        return self.__product_names.get(name)


x = Catalog()
x.__product_names = {'x': 1, 'y':2}
print(x.search_products_by_name('x'))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**What's happening in this code?**

The code above seems fine, but has some behaviour that might seem unusual. If we type this in an interactive console:

```
c = Catalog()
# vars() returns the instance dict of an object,
# showing us the value of all its attributes at this point in time.
vars(c)
```

Then the result is this:

```
{'_Catalog__product_names': {}}
```

That's pretty weird! In our class definition, we didn't give any attribute the name `_Catalog__product_names`. We named one attribute `__product_names`, but that attribute appears to have been renamed.

**What's going on**

This behaviour isn't a bug — it's actually a feature of python known as [*private name mangling*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables). For all attributes that you define in a class definition, if the attribute name begins with two leading underscores — and does *not* end with two trailing underscores — then the attribute will be renamed like this. An attribute named `__foo` in class `Bar` will be renamed `_Bar__foo`; an attribute named `__spam` in class `Breakfast` will be renamed `_Breakfast__spam`; etc, etc.

The name mangling only occurs for when you try to access the attribute from outside the class. Methods within the class can still access the attribute using its "private" name that you defined in `__init__`.

**Why would you ever want this?**

I personally have never found a use case for this feature, and am somewhat sceptical of it. Its main use cases are for situations where you want a method or an attribute to be privately accessible within a class, but not accessible by the same name to functions outside of the class *or to other classes inheriting from this class*.

- Some use cases here:
  [What is the benefit of private name mangling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162234/what-is-the-benefit-of-private-name-mangling)
- And here's a good [YouTube talk](https://youtu.be/HTLu2DFOdTg) that includes some use cases for
  this feature about 34 minutes in.

(N.B. The YouTube talk is from 2013, and the examples in the talk are written in python 2, so some of the syntax in the examples is a little different from modern python — `print` is still a statement rather than a function, etc.)

Here is an illustration of how private name mangling works when using class inheritance:

```
>>> class Foo:
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.__private_attribute = 'No one shall ever know'
...   def baz_foo(self):
...     print(self.__private_attribute)
...     
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...   def baz_bar(self):
...     print(self.__private_attribute)
...     
>>> 
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.baz_foo()
No one shall ever know
>>> 
>>> b.baz_bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in baz_bar
AttributeError: 'Bar' object has no attribute '_Bar__private_attribute'
>>>
>>> vars(b)
{'_Foo__private_attribute': 'No one shall ever know'}
>>>
>>> b._Foo__private_attribute
'No one shall ever know'
```

The methods defined in the base class `Foo` are able to access the private attribute using its private name that was defined in `Foo`. The methods defined in the subclass `Bar`, however, are only able to access the private attribute by using its mangled name; anything else leads to an exception.

`collections.OrderedDict` is a [good example](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/83ca46b7784b7357d82ec47b33295e09ed7380cb/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L78) of a class in the standard library that makes extensive use of name-mangling to ensure that subclasses of `OrderedDict` do not accidentally override certain methods in `OrderedDict` that are important to the way `OrderedDict`  works.

**How do I fix this?**

The obvious solution here is to rename your attribute so that it only has a single leading underscore, like so. This still sends a clear signal to external users that this is a private attribute that should not be directly modified by functions or classes outside of the class, but does not lead to any weird name mangling behaviour:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Search(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def search_products_by_name(self, name):
        print('found', name)


class Catalog(Search):
    def __init__(self):
        self._product_names = {}
    
    def search_products_by_name(self, name):
        super().search_products_by_name(name)
        return self._product_names.get(name)


x = Catalog()
x._product_names = {'x': 1, 'y':2}
print(x.search_products_by_name('x'))
```

Another solution is to roll with the name mangling, either like this:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Search(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def search_products_by_name(self, name):
        print('found', name)


class Catalog(Search):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__product_names = {}
    
    def search_products_by_name(self, name):
        super().search_products_by_name(name)
        return self.__product_names.get(name)


x = Catalog()
# we have to use the mangled name when accessing it from outside the class
x._Catalog__product_names = {'x': 1, 'y':2}
print(x.search_products_by_name('x'))
```

Or — and this is probably better, since it's just a bit weird to be accessing an attribute using its mangled name from outside the class — like this:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Search(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def search_products_by_name(self, name):
        print('found', name)


class Catalog(Search):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__product_names = {}
    
    def search_products_by_name(self, name):
        super().search_products_by_name(name)
        return self.__product_names.get(name)

    def set_product_names(self, product_names):
        # we can still use the private name from within the class
        self.__product_names = product_names


x = Catalog()
x.set_product_names({'x': 1, 'y':2})
print(x.search_products_by_name('x'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of double-underscore is to avoid name clashes with names defined by subclasses. it is not a way to indicate that something is 'private', as Python does not have the concepts of preventing access.

A situation where `__` is useful would be this:

```
class Product:
   discount = 5
   __init__(self, name, price):
      self.name = name
      self.price = price

class Item(Product):
   def discount(self):
      self.price = self.price * 0.9
```

`discount` classes with the methodname of the subclass. If `__discount` was used, that name of the variable would become `_Product__discount`.

If there are no subclasses, there is no point in using `__`

In your code there is no reason to use a ABC, and could be easily written in more pythonic way:

```
class Catalog:
    def __init__(self, products=None):
        self.products = products

    def search_products(self, name):
        return [item for item in self.products if name in item]


x = Catalog()
x.products = [{"x": 1}, {"y": 2}, {"x": 5}]
results = x.search_products(name="x")  
# [{'x': 1}, {'x': 5}]
```

Comment: It's definitely important to note that Python's concept of "private" variables is *very* different to the idea of private variables in other languages. "Private name mangling" is the name commonly used to refer to this feature, however, and indeed the documentation refers to this feature in a section subtitled **Private Variables**. (I have upvoted your answer nonetheless, as the distinction you raise is an important one.) https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables