# private class variable in inherited class method

Tags: python

I tried an experiment over the concept of class variable (private and public), accessed from class method like this:

```
class Foo:
    __x = 1 
    y = 2 

    @classmethod
    def get_x(cls):
        return cls.__x

    @classmethod
    def get_y(cls):
        return cls.y
    
class Goo(Foo):
    __x = 3
    y = 4


g = Goo()
print("x=%d" % g.get_x())
print("y=%d" % g.get_y())
```

The results:

```
x=1
y=4
```

I want `g.get_x()` to return `GOO.__x`, like `g.get_y()` does for `Goo.__y`. How can I do it?

Comment: While [What is the benefit of private name mangling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1162234/364696) is helpful information, it is not answering this question, nor is the question a duplicate.

Comment: `__x` isn't really private. The point of name mangling is to avoid just the kind of subclass attribute *shadowing* that you are trying to use here.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how *private* variables work. The whole point of private variables is that are *private* to that *specific* class. When a method defined in `Foo` asks for `__x`, it *only* gets the `__x` for that class. When a method defined in `Goo` asks for `__x`, it *only* gets the `__x` from `Goo`. It's *private*, so there is no overlap where a subclass's version of it can inadvertently override the parent class's from the point of view of the parent class (unless both classes have the same name).

If you *really* want to do this, you can, but it involves some rigmarole. Specifically, you need to manually perform the name-mangling yourself, by extracting the runtime name of the class you received, and manually calling `getattr`, e.g.:

```
@classmethod
def get_x(cls):
    return getattr(cls, f'_{cls.__name__}__x')
```

This works because private names undergo name-mangling to change them from `__privatename` to `_CLASSNAME__privatename` when accessed from within the context of that class. You can perform the same mangling manually if you truly want to bypass this protection. It's a *bad* idea (and in this case, *requires* the subclass to have a private variable of the same name, though a more complicated solution could traverse the MRO to find the first class with such a private name), as it [breaks the protections private names are supposed to provide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1162234/364696), and if the two classes are maintained independently, can easily break when the other class (which believes its private attributes are not part of the public API) changes them.

In practice, if you want sharing like this, you usually just prefix the attribute name with a *single* underscore, so it's logically non-public, but not subject to name-mangling; using `_x` as the consistent name of your class attribute would allow your code to work as expected.